# Tuning Hadoop job execution on YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

A bit of intro - I'm learning about Hadoop. I have implemented machine learning algorithm on top of Hadoop (clustering) and tested it only on a small example (30MB).

A couple of days ago I installed Ambari and created a small cluster of four machines (master and 3 workers). Master has Resource manager and NameNode.

Now I'm testing my algorithm by increasing the amount of data (300MB, 3GB). I'm looking for a pointer how to tune up my mini-cluster. Concretely, I would like to know how to determine MapReduce2 and YARN settings in Ambari.

**How to determine min/max memory for container, reserved memory for container, Sort Allocation Memory, map memory and reduce memory?**

The problem is that execution of my jobs is very slow on Hadoop (and clustering is an iterative algorithm, which makes things worse).

I have a feeling that my cluster setup is not good, because of the following reason:

- I run a job for a dataset of 30MB (I set-up block memory for this job to be 8MB, since data is small and processing is intensive) - execution time 30 minutes
- I run the same job, but multiply same dataset 10 times - 300MB (same block size, 8MB) - execution time 2 hours
- Now same amount of data - 300MB, but block size 128MB - same execution time, maybe even a bit greater than 2 hours

Size of blocks on HDFS is 128MB, so I thought that this will cause the speedup, but that is not the case. My doubts are that the cluster setup (min/max RAM size, map and reduce RAM) is not good, hence it cannot improve even though greater data locality is achieved.

**Could this be the consequence of a bad setup, or am I wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Please set the below properties in Yarn configuratins to allocate 33% of max yarn memory per job, which can be altered based on your requirement.

yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=0.33
If you need further info on this, please refer following link https://analyticsanvil.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/managing-yarn-memory-with-multiple-hive-users/